# 'New' tags on Windows 10 Start Menu items keep returning

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1709

My Windows 10 desktop just 'updated' to 1709 (16299.64) and I've noticed something peculiar. Certain items on the Start Menu have 'New' tags after the update while others don't, despite my not having installed anything new. It's not just Store apps either – some Win32 apps sport the tag as well:

[image: Unnecessary 'New' tags in Windows 10 1709 (16299.64) Start Menu]

What's really irritating is that even if I right-click or launch the items and remove the 'New' tags, every time I sign out and sign back in, or restart, or shut down and reboot into Windows, the tags are back like bad pennies!

How do I make them disappear for good?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.v2ex.com/amp/t/444426

Execute the following under Admin Powershell:

Remove-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\' -Force -Recurse
Get-Process Explorer | Stop-Process